# Passing a captured binary file through snort

Tags: snort

Is it possible to pass pre-captured binary files through snort for analysis (with flagging or detection as the ultimate goal)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-r` option for that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16644843)

Comment: I have not done any critique nor request to the user. The user is asking how to use snort to analyze a pcap file, and I've answered that snort has a parameter for that (the cited `-r`).

Comment: @KobyDouek This answer leaves a lot of room for improvement. But it is a valid answer nonetheless.